# Dificudades em fazer uma consulta SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou realizando um projeto para faculdade porém venho tendo dificuldades com consultas ao SQLite. Gostaria que pudessem me auxiliar nessa questão.

OnCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chamado);

    buscarDados();
    criaLista();

}
```

buscarDados:

```
public void buscarDados(){
     try{
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("cadastro",Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING,null);
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from cadastro",null);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dados encontrados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

criarLista:

```
public void criaLista(){
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    String[] dados = {"titulo"};
    int[] to = {R.id.lista};

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.activity_chamado,cursor,dados,to);

    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Qual a dificuldade que você esta tendo?

Comment: Simples a minha query de consulta nunca funciona sempre retorna erro.

Comment: Felipe, qual o erro que a consulta retorna? Minha primeira sugestão é usar uma AsyncTask ou um CursorLoader para fazer sua consulta e popular seu adapter (o primeiro é mais simples), porque está fazendo acesso a disco na `Main Thread`, que é "proibído" (você pode fazer, mas não é uma boa prática).